# How to insert line breaks into comma-separated parenthetical data?

Tags: replace, freebsd

I have a set of data in a text file that looks like this:

```
(1,2,3),(A,B,C),(4,5,6)
```

I want those parenthetical segments to be on their own lines, preserving the commas between them:

```
(1,2,3),
(A,B,C),
(4,5,6)
```

I have tried many combinations of `sed` and `tr` and `awk`, but none of them produce the desired result. They leave the data on one line with an added r or n, or they eat the first open parenthesis on the next line, or they have other parsing problems.

This finally worked on my local computer (Linux):

```
sed -r 's/\),\(+/\),\r\(/g' file > file
```

But it failed on the remote server where I need it to work (FreeBSD). I have yet to find anything that works in FreeBSD.

I've been at this for hours. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot (easily) use a '\n' escape sequence in the replacement pattern with sed, you can place an actual newline by using a backslash at the end of the line.

### From stdin

```
# echo '(1,2,3),(A,B,C),(4,5,6)' | sed -e 's/),/),\
/g'
(1,2,3),
(A,B,C),
(4,5,6)
```

### From file

```
# sed -e 's/),/),\
/g' infile
```

I tested this with FreeBSD 11.2 and Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this:

```
$ echo '(1,2,3),(A,B,C),(4,5,6)' | sed -e $'s/),/),\\\n/g'
```

Notice the `$''` , It will help to replace `\n` with a real newline, test by doing:

```
$ echo $'s/),/),\\\n/g'
s/),/),\
/g
```

You will need `sh`, won't work if you are using the default `csh` shell in FreeBSD.

If you can't change the shell and only have `csh`, this works:

```
$ echo '(1,2,3),(A,B,C),(4,5,6)' | perl -pe 's/\),/\),\n/g'
```

Both options will output:

```
(1,2,3),
(A,B,C),
(4,5,6)
```